# Organizing dataset to fit a linear model

Tags: r, statistics

My goal is to fit a model (lm or glm) to the dataset

```
url <- paste0("https://10d9b011-755b-4b59-9f64-dbfb2ae95d87.filesusr.com/",
                  "ugd/0c24ab_a29a977ec1404b69bf7cc34fcc58b073.csv?",
                  "dn=Aus%20GP%20Lap%20Data.csv")

df <- read.csv(url)
```

On the form ( I think this is what makes sense for what I want to model)

```
model <- lm(position_lap_58 ~ driverId + position_at_lap1)
```

In short, I want to model or analyze the general relationship between the the drivers starting position and their finishing result. I also with to calculate the correlation between starting and finishing positions.

```
cor(position_lap_1, position_lap_58)
```

My problem is that I haven't yet been able to make the correct operations on the dataset to create variables on the form that allows me to do this. I have tried various things using `dplyr` functions `%>%` pipes etc, but I just can't seem do it quite the way that I want to.

so if anyone knows a nice way to do this that would help me a alot.

Comment: You have not shown us where the variables in your model come from. The `paste0` command will not run as posted. Have you downloaded the data yet? That is the first step.

Comment: I have downloaded the data set and imported it locally from my computer, I was just providing the url for the data set for others to import (I have edited the code in the post). I have already worked with the data set and computed various statistics and relationships (compared and plotted the mean lap times for every year, calculated correlations between mean lap times and standard deviation for every year etc). My problem is that I can't figure out how to modify the data set such that I can fit a linear model of the form I described.